# Map over object except for last key - Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I map over the keys of `Object` using `Object.entries()`:

```
<div>
return Object.entries(obj).map([key, value]){
    <span key={key}> {key}: {value} </span>
}
</div>
```

And `obj` looks like this:

```
{
    group: ‘name’,
    address: ‘Address’,
    manager: ‘John’,
    products: [
        {
        electronic: ‘laptop’,
        team: ‘Awesome’
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the above mapping, I understandably get the following in the :

```
group: name
address: Address
manager: John
products: [object object] [object object]
```

How can I render everything except last key (products) to have the following shown in div:

```
group: name
address: Address
manager: John
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the check on type of value, if type is `object` then skip that part from rendering. By this way it will skip `objects and arrays`.

```
typeof([])  ==> 'object'

typeof({})  ==> 'object'
```

Like this:

```js
var data = {
    group: 'name',
    address: 'Address',
    manager: 'John',
    products: [
        {
           electronic: 'laptop',
           team: 'Awesome'
        }
    ]
}

Object.entries(data).map(([key, val], index) => {
     if(typeof(val) != 'object') {
        console.log(key, val, index);   //return the span 
     }
     else null;
})
```

Replace `console.log(key, val, index)` by `<span key={key}> {key}: {value} </span>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<div>
return Object.entries(obj).map([key, value], i, arr){
    if (i !== arr.length - 1) {
      <span key={key}> {key}: {value} </span>
    }
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of keys in the object using `arr.length` as third parameter to the map function and compare with the `index` in the map function like below snippet. Also You are returning the data incorrectly from map

```js
var data = {
    group: 'name',
    address: 'Address',
    manager: 'John',
    products: [
        {
        electronic: 'laptop',
        team: 'Awesome'
        }
    ]
}
var len = Object.keys(data).length;
Object.entries(data).map(([key, val], index, arr) => {
     if(index !== arr.length - 1) {
     console.log(key, val, index);
     }
})
```

You code being

```
<div>
 {Object.entries(obj).map([key, value], index, arr){
    if(index < arr.length) {
          return   <span key={key}> {key}: {value} </span>
    } 
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter before map:

```
var data = {
    'group': 'name',
    'address': 'Address',
    'manager': 'John',
    'products': [
        {
            'electronic' 'laptop',
            'team': 'Awesome
        }
    ]
}

return Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => {
  if (typeof value !== 'object' ) return 1;
}).map(([key, value]) => {
    <span key={key}> {key}: {value} </span>
});
```

Here any key that is having value as object would be eliminated.

Will return:

```
group: name
address: Address
manager: John
```